# .NET Core: Is there an equivalent of MSBuild tasks in the new project.json format?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, .net-core, project.json

I'm a big fan of MSBuild tasks like GitVersionTask, xUnit.MSBuild or OctoPack and use them to version, test and package my assemblies during build time.

Here's my question:

Is there an alternative or equivalent to MSBuild tasks in the new .NET Core world where you have project.json files instead of csproj files?

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/05/project-json http://ivanz.com/2016/05/17/farewell-project-json-hello-msbuild-and-csproj You must be happy that Microsoft moves back to MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

Like Danny mentioned, project.json has some elementary script hooks for the various stages. However, .NET CLI does not consider itself as a first class build system. Since you are a fan, you can use msbuild with .NET Core since it was recently ported to it. I have no idea in which state it is, but at least their CI builds are running.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/23/porting-msbuild-to-net-core/ => Their porting story

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild => source code

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the scripts section of a project.json file to see if it fulfills your requirements? It can run anything you could also run from the command line. At various stages, like prebuild, postbuild, republish, etc.